# FullCalendar best practice for calling API on date change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, vuex

I have a FullCalendar (Vue package), in the "[resourceTimeGridDay](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view)" view configuartion.

For my situation, I have an API that responds with an array of [events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing) and [resources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-object). Right now I'm listening for the [datesRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesRender) method to fire and sending a GET request to the API for the user-selected day.

This works fine, however due to the nature of Vue and Vuex - the Calendar renders itself again when the Vuex state changes (resulting in multiple API calls).

It feels like a code smell to me, so I'm wondering what is considered best practice when fetching calendar date from an API?

Comment: Don't use datesRender. As recommended in the fullCalendar documentation and examples, you should use one the event feed patterns described [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) or [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function). Once you define a URL or a function as a source of events, fullCalendar will automatically visit the URL (or call the function) to request new events whenever the date or the view changes. When it does that, it will automatically provide the start and end dats of the new view, so that the server / function can filter the events returned.

Comment: And you can use both the same patterns for resources too - see [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-json-feed) and [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-function)

Comment: @ADyson is there a way to use the feed patterns and still keep the events in the vuex store?

Comment: I don't know anything about vue so I'm not really sure what you're asking, sorry.